# Rails 3, @font-face failing in production with firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-face, asset-pipeline, font-awesome

I'm using [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) in a rails 3 app, and everything is ok in development mode, but when I push to Heroku, Firefox fails to render the icons, and instead, I see this:

[image]

- Chrome renders the icons fine in development and production
- This just affects FireFox (although I've not tried IE)
- The app is [here](https://pure-sunset-9274.herokuapp.com), I'd appreciate if someone could confirm that this is not just happening on my machine (to help me rule out a localhost caching issue).
- All assets, including fonts and stylesheets, are hosted on S3, using the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem.

**Here's what I've done:**

Added the following to the top of font-awesome.css.scss:**

```
// font-awesome.css.scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
  src: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),
       font-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
       font-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
       font-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I put this in application.rb:

```
# application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

Finaly I placed all 4 font files in `app/assets/fonts`.

I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fixed my problem.

From [this article](http://blog.fallingmanstudios.net/post/14281163243/firefox-font-face-in-rails-with-asset-subdomains#notes), I learned that:

> Firefox rejects all cross-site font requests unless some specific headers are set:
>
> [i.e. Access-Control-Allow-Origin]

And, from [this article](http://motoole.com/2011/10/19/hosting-font-face-fonts-on-s3.html):

> Sadly, right now S3 doesn’t allow you to specify the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header that your objects get served with

So you have a few options:

1. Serve the fonts from your app's public folder, not from S3
2. Serve the fonts from Rackspace, where you **can** set the headers
3. Embed the font in your as a [Base64 string](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/)

I've gone with the first option since this is gonna be a low traffic site, but here's a nice write-up on how to [serve fonts from Rackspace](http://www.bryandragon.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline-cdns-and-serving-cross-domain-fonts) whilst simultaneously serving all other assets from S3.

---

**UPDATE:**

Amazon [announced yesterday](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/08/31/amazon-s3-announces-cross-origin-resource-sharing-CORS-support/) that they now support Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), so the solution posted above should no longer be necessary. Their [developer guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) explains more.

Comment: i am facing the same problem except that my application is hosted on heroku? the fonts are loading on chrome, chromium, safari but not on firefox and IE8. could you please point me in the right direction to solve the problem? i am using rails 4, BS 3 with font awesome. thanks.

Answer (score 25):

This is the configuration I added to my bucket in AWS management console to configure this cross thing:

Log in to AWS -> AWS Management Console -> S3 -> Find your Bucket -> Push properties button (magnifying glass on paper for some reason) -> Clic PERMISSIONS on the right -> "Edit CORS configuration"

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

After two hours of researches...  :-(

Comment: If it makes you feel better, you just saved me two hours. Thanks!

Comment: If it makes YOU feel better, I have wasted three days on this. Thanks!

Comment: how to do this in rails

Comment: @AmitSuroliya: what do you mean? This is rails + AWS. The issue was on the AWS side.

Comment: Hey...thanks for reply....i mean, i am using rails 4 and i got an issue related with font-awesome in production firefox. I  am using font-awesome file as a partial scss and it is perfectly working in chrome, safari etc.But it is not working in firefox. I know that it is problem related with CORS origin, then i try using font_assets gem also, but my problem is still there. Can u help me ?? thanks in advance....

Comment: Just want to add how you use this. Log in to AWS -> AWS Management Console -> S3 -> Find your Bucket -> Push p roperties button (magnifying glass on paper for some reason) -> Clic PERMISSIONS on the right -> "Edit CORS configuration" -> Paste in the code from this answer. Worked for me once I figured out what to do, Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Amazon S3 now support CORS, you're no longer forced to embed BASE64 fonts in your css (it will save you some bandwidth :)

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/08/31/amazon-s3-announces-cross-origin-resource-sharing-CORS-support/

Comment: thanks, i already added that link to the accepted answer yesterday, cheers

Answer (score 5):

You can also use some rack middleware to serve the fonts directly with the required access-control headers to cloudfront.

```
# config/environment/production.rb

  # Rack Headers
  # Set HTTP Headers on static assets

  config.assets.header_rules = {
    :global => {'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=31536000'},
    :fonts  => {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'}
  }
  require 'rack_headers'
  config.middleware.insert_before '::ActionDispatch::Static', '::Rack::Headers'

-----

# lib/rack_headers.rb

require 'rack/utils'

module Rack
  class Headers

    def initialize(app, options={})
      @app = app

      default_path = Rails.application.config.assets.prefix || '/assets'
      @asset_path = options.fetch(:path, default_path)

      default_rules = Rails.application.config.assets.header_rules || {}
      @rules = options.fetch(:header_rules, default_rules)
    end

    def call(env)
      dup._call(env)
    end

    def _call(env)
      status, @headers, response = @app.call(env)
      @path = ::Rack::Utils.unescape(env['PATH_INFO'])

      if @path.start_with?(@asset_path)
        set_headers
      end

      [status, @headers, response]
    end

    def set_headers
      @rules.each do |rule, headers|
        case rule
        when :global # Global
          set_header(headers)
        when :fonts  # Fonts Shortcut
          set_header(headers) if @path.match %r{\.(?:ttf|otf|eot|woff|svg)\z}
        when Array   # Extension/Extensions
          extensions = rule.join('|')
          set_header(result) if @path.match %r{\.(#{extensions})\z}
        when String  # Folder
          set_header(result) if
            (@path.start_with? rule || @path.start_with?('/' + rule))
        when Regexp  # Flexible Regexp
          set_header(result) if @path.match rule
        else
        end
      end
    end

    def set_header(headers)
      headers.each { |field, content| @headers[field] = content }
    end
  end
end

-----
```

This solution uses rules for setting different headers on every file based on rules. The rules are described here: https://github.com/thomasklemm/butler#providing-rules-for-setting-http-headers. Basically you can do anything with Regexps, but there are shortcuts for file endings, folders, web fonts and global headers.

Comment: Nice tip, thanks for the link too - butler looks like a very useful gem

Comment: The underlying Rack::File implementation didn't allow for setting custom HTTP headers up to very recently. A commit has just been accepted bringing in this functionality, but there is not official release yet (it will be in 1.4.2+). I expect Rails's very own ActionDispatch::Static will have the functionality to add custom headers then by a `config.assets.http_header_rules = {}` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following site to Base64 Encode a font. Tried using FontSquirel but it does not let you encrypt copyright / bought fonts.

http://base64fonts.com/convert.php

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the header for your whole bucket in s3.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html

Answer (score 0):

There's an update to this thread. It seems that it's not possible to set CORS by uploading cors.xml file to a bucket. Now you have to CLICK it ;). This thread saved me some time while looking for a solution, but on the other hand I lost some time uploading and changing cors.xml file.

The current solution is to click on a bucket's properties > Permissons > and then click Add CORS Configuration