# Rails 3.2.x - cannot set up font-face on localhost

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, font-face

Whole day I am trying to set up to work `@font-face` on localhost. Here's my setup:

`application.rb` and `development.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

In CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'my_font';
  src: asset-url('font_name.eot', font);
  src: asset-url('font_name.eot?#iefix', font) format('embedded-opentype'),
       asset-url('font_name.woff', font) format('woff'),
       asset-url('font_name.ttf', font)  format('truetype'),
       asset-url('font_name.svg#AndrogyneMedium', font) format('svg');    
}
```

I've tried also to precompile assets:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I've tried also couple times to restart app, but nothing didn't help me.

Could anyone give me any advice, how to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** 
Ok guys, I'll give you zillion dollars who help me to solve it :) I've tried probably everything...

Comment: This sounds stupid, but have you checked to see if the font urls are resolving?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the files to the precompile config as well:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.svg *.eot *.ttf *.woff)
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled on this issue to so my solution was to see if [typekit](https://typekit.com/) had the font that I was looking for in which they did and I kept it moving. You should not spend hours worrying about fonts but rather the code so check it out because it will save you the time and headache.

Answer (score 0):

If you organize your fonts in `assets/fonts` you can use the following setup.

```
# config/application.rb
# Serve fonts via Asset Pipeline
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

I'm using the font-awesome icon font, so in the `font-awesome.sass` I use a `font-url` helper (that differs from your `asset-url`).

```
# vendor/stylesheets/font-awesome.sass
@import compass/css3/font-face

@font-face
  font-family: 'FontAwesome'
  src: font-url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot")
  src: font-url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("eot"), font-url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format("woff"), font-url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), font-url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format("svg")
```

Source: [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261805/rails-3-font-face-failing-in-production-with-firefox)

Comment: I don't know what am I doing wrong, but I have exactly this setup and it still doesn't work... still those new fonts don't work.

Comment: Hi Thomas... trying & trying, but unfortunately, the same... the fonts are not loaded.