# Using a Self-Hosted Webfont, Google says: Font has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, webfonts

I'm self hosting 2 Webfonts which displayed smoothly and nice on my website across all browsers for almost 3 weeks.

Today I noticed that Safari is the only browser that still displays the fonts correctly. Chrome and Firefox are no longer loading these webfonts and instead use the CSS defined fallbacks. Chromes Console told me  about these specific fonts:

> Font from origin 'http://www.-----.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://crispin-m.de' is therefore not allowed
>   access. "

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You might [find this helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261805/rails-3-font-face-failing-in-production-with-firefox).

Comment: Redirect www to none www, or the other way round. Or add the [header to your font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header)